# Use a certificate in the keyvault to access multi-tenant application in other tenant

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault

We have a multi-tenant application in our Azure AD tenant. It is authorized in some other tenants (we know which ones). And it has multiple certificates registered to it to be used as client credentials.

We want to remove the certificates from the local stores and use a certificate in the key vault to request a token for one of the external tenant. According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/service-to-service-authentication#use-a-certificate-in-key-vault-to-sign-into-azure-ad) this is one of the use cases.

Our tenant (id: xxxx):

- Has app registration (app id: abcd-xxx-xxxx-xxx)
- has keyvault
- has managed service principal (with access to the key vault)

other tenant (id: yyyy):

- Executed [Admin consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/grant-admin-consent#construct-the-url-for-granting-tenant-wide-admin-consent) for our application.

### Question 1:

How do I create a certificate in the Key vault that is connected to an existing application (app id: abcd-xxx-xxxx-xxx)? It is important to note that since the application is already approved by several third party admins, it cannot be recreated. Same counts for creating a new certificate after it would be expired.

### Question 2:

How to I setup the [Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/service-to-service-authentication#using-the-library) library to:

1. Use the managed identity to access the key vault in our tenant (xxxx).
2. Use the certificate in the key vault to request a token for our app (abcd-xxx-xxxx-xxx) in other companies tenant (yyyy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer 1:**

You could use [`az ad sp credential reset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/sp/credential?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-sp-credential-reset) command like below. If you don't want to overwrite the existing certificate of the App, please pass the `--append` parameter.

```
az ad sp credential reset --name '<application-id>' --keyvault joykeyvault --cert cer136 --create-cert --append
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Answer 2:**

1.To use the MSI access the keyvault in your tenant, just use the code below.

No code changes are required, when you run your code on an Azure App Service or an Azure VM with a managed identity enabled, the library automatically uses the managed identity, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/service-to-service-authentication#running-the-application-using-managed-identity-or-user-assigned-identity).

The environment variable `AzureServicesAuthConnectionString` has to be set to any [credential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/service-to-service-authentication#connection-string-support) with access to the keyvault. `RunAs=Developer; DeveloperTool=AzureCli` for dev or `RunAs=App;` for managed service identity (automatically in azure).

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication;
using Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault;

// Instantiate a new KeyVaultClient object, with an access token to Key Vault
var azureServiceTokenProvider1 = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
var kv = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider1.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
```

2.If you want to use the service principal along with its certificate stored in the keyvault to get the token for the resources in another tenant, the connection string on the AzureServiceTokenProvider has to be set to `RunAs=App;AppId={TestAppId};KeyVaultCertificateSecretIdentifier={KeyVaultCertificateSecretIdentifier}` then you can get tokens for other tenants like.

```
const string appWithCertConnection = "RunAs=App;AppId={TestAppId};KeyVaultCertificateSecretIdentifier=https://myKeyVault.vault.azure.net/secrets/myCert";
```

Then use the code to get the token, e.g. for the resource `https://management.azure.com/`.

```
var azureServiceTokenProvider2 = new AzureServiceTokenProvider(appWithCertConnection);
string accessToken = await azureServiceTokenProvider2.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", "tenant-id-of-thridh-party-tenant").ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: The MSI also uses the environment variable right `RunAs=App`? So how does the second token provider get access to the keyvault in tenant 1, if the environment variable is set to `TenantID:tenant2`.

Comment: Answer 1: is great, maybe that should be in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/service-to-service-authentication#running-the-application-using-managed-identity-or-user-assigned-identity)

Comment: @Stephan From the description of the doc, we may just need to use the `azureServiceTokenProvider2` without the `azureServiceTokenProvider1 `, when specify the `KeyVaultCertificateSecretIdentifier` in the `AzureServicesAuthConnectionString `, looks it will get the certificate automatically, then use it along with the service principal.

Comment: do you have a link where you found that documentation? It sounds like a really good solution for us.

Comment: @Stephan There is no doc about the multi-tenant scenario, I just look into this [link](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-msi-keyvault-dotnet#running-the-application-using-a-service-principal-in-local-development-environment), it seems to be similar, but I am not 100% sure it will work, you can have a try first.

Comment: I've submitted an edit to your answer with tested code. Once approved this can be marked as solved.